# google cloud dataflow cross project access for big table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I want to run dataflow job to migrate data from google-project-1-table to google-project-2-table. (Read from one and write to another). I am getting permission issue while doing that. I have set "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" to point to my credential file for project-1. In project-2 below are the permissions/roles for project-1. 1) service-account (role - Editor) 2) -compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com (role - Editor) 3) @cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com(role - Editor).

Is there anything else I need to do to run the job?

> Caused by: com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.grpc.io.IOExceptionWithStatus: Error in response stream
>           at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.grpc.scanner.ResultQueueEntry$ExceptionResultQueueEntry.getResponseOrThrow(ResultQueueEntry.java:66)
>           at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.grpc.scanner.ResponseQueueReader.getNextMergedRow(ResponseQueueReader.java:55)
>           at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.grpc.scanner.StreamingBigtableResultScanner.next(StreamingBigtableResultScanner.java:42)
>           at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.grpc.scanner.StreamingBigtableResultScanner.next(StreamingBigtableResultScanner.java:27)
>           at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:89)
>           at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:45)
>           at com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableIO$1.next(CloudBigtableIO.java:221)
>           at com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableIO$1.next(CloudBigtableIO.java:216)
>           at com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableIO$Reader.advance(CloudBigtableIO.java:775)
>           at com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableIO$Reader.start(CloudBigtableIO.java:799)
>           at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.Read$Bounded$1.evaluateReadHelper(Read.java:178)
>           ... 18 more
>   Caused by: com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User can't access project: project-2
>           at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:431)
>           at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.grpc.scanner.StreamObserverAdapter.onClose(StreamObserverAdapter.java:48)
>           at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$3.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:462)
>           at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:54)
>           at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:154)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           ... 1 more

Answer (score 2):

There are some instructions for this in the section "[Accessing Cloud Platform Resources Across Multiple Cloud Platform Projects](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions#accessing-cloud-platform-resources-across-multiple-cloud-platform-projects)" of the Dataflow Security and Permissions guide.

Since that guide does not explicitly address Cloud BigTable, I will try to write up the requirements clearly here in terms of your question.

Using fake project id numbers, it seems you have:

- A project `project-1` with id *12345*.
- A project `project-2` with id *9876*
- A Bigtable `google-project-1-table` in `project-1`
- A Bigtable `google-project-2-table` in `project-2`
- A Dataflow pipeline that will run in `project-1`, which you want to:

  - read from `google-project-1-table`
  - write to `google-project-2-table`

Is that accurate?

Your Dataflow workers that write to Bigtable run as the compute engine service account. That is `12345-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`. This account will need to be able to access `project-2` and write to `google-project-2-table`.

Your error message implies that the permissions failure occurs at the coarsest granularity - the account cannot access `project-2` at all.

Comment: sorry I updated the error message. Permission denied I am getting for project-2 (while using project-1 credentials). I went through that document. Is there anything I should look at specifically. I also have read/write permissions [for both the projects] to the staginglocation-bucket I am using for this job.